# Finding the value of the sum $\sum_{r=0}^{1006}{2012\choose 2r}{(-3)^r}$

Tags: complex-numbers, summation

The given question says that find
$$\sum_{r=0}^{1006}{2012\choose 2r}{(-3)^r}$$
The answer given to the problem is that the above sum is real part of $$\left(\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}\right)^{2012} \cdot 2^{2012}$$

Now I have no idea where this came from. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$
\newcommand{\floor}[1]{\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor}
$Consider the binomial expansions

$$\begin{align*}
(x+y)^n &= \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} x^{n-k} y^{k} \\
(x-y)^n &= \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} x^{n-k} y^{ k} (-1)^{ k}
\end{align*}$$

If you summed these, the terms of odd index cancel out, giving

$$(x+y)^n + (x-y)^n = 2\sum_{\substack{0 \le k \le n \\ k \text{ even}}} \binom{n}{k} x^{n-k} y^{ k} $$

Reindex as so... Since $k$ must be even, let $k = 2r$. Then replace $n$ with $\floor{n/2}$ in the upper bound, giving

$$(x+y)^n + (x-y)^n = 2\sum_{r=0}^{\floor{n/2}} \binom{n}{2r} x^{n-2r} y^{ 2r} $$

---

Notice how this fits your summation, if...

- $n=2012$
- $x=1$
- $y = \sqrt{-3} = \sqrt 3i \implies y^{2r} = (-3)^r$
- We divide by two

Therefore,

$$\sum_{r=0}^{1006} \binom{2012}{2r} (-3)^r = \frac{1}{2} \Big( (1+i\sqrt3 )^{2012} + (1-i\sqrt3 )^{2012} \Big)$$

Notice that if $z := 1+i\sqrt3 $, then $\overline{z} = 1-i\sqrt3 $, meaning we have conjugates. Of course, $z + \overline{z} = 2 \cdot \mathfrak{Re}(z)$. Hence,

$$\sum_{r=0}^{1006} \binom{2012}{2r} (-3)^r = \mathfrak{Re} \Big( (1+i\sqrt3 )^{2012} \Big)$$

From here, to get to your expression is fairly straightforward. I imagine you can simplify this much further, but it seems beyond the scope of your question.